# Minnowing Campaign

Tags: network

I came across this term "minnowing campaign" against mobile users on an exam. What is minnowing campaign? The search on public domain didn't reveal anything relating to network security.

Comment: What exam? Can you provide any more context?

Comment: Sorry becoz of NDA with exam authorities i am not in a position to reveal the name of the exam. I would be happy to explain whats MC though if you are interested

Comment: If you have an answer to this question, I can re-open it so you can provide your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad exam. [Symantec](https://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/err-human-part-1) think it is targeting "less significant members of a company such as receptionists". While a [Reuters](http://www.loosewireblog.com/2005/06/more_on_minnow_.html) correspondent describes minnow phishing as targetting small financial institutions. I've also heard the term applied to attacks on users of micropayment services (which may tie into your reference to mobile devices).

This appears to be an emergent term which has not yet acquired a consensus usage. Go write the wikipedia page then you're guaranteed to get the answer right.